# Find and high light all numbers in a certain range: MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

**Using Microsoft Word 2013, how do I highlight all numbers in a certain range.**

I already found out how to find and highlight all of a certain number, but this would be a big help.

Example: I want to find all numbers between 2300 and 2500 and highlight them. Each number however might be    *.2300       *.2301     etc.

Worst case senario, highlighting just any number in a range is the ultimate question, a prefix of *. is only a plus.

update to question:
Note: To state exactly what I am doing - I have a document where a netstat was run on about 100 different machines. the numbers are mixed up with tons of other information. Copying and pasting the numbers to another program would take as much time as highlighting the numbers myself with the highlight tool. Thank you all for your answers so far and I appreciate the advise. I am starting to think the answer may be "No" in word and "Yes" in another program.

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced--eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tool for the right job, [Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en-us/excel) is an electronic spreadsheet program that can be used for storing, organizing and manipulating data. There is a function called `conditional formatting` that automatic highlight cells when a conditional met

I dont have English excel installed so I search this image from the Internet, you should use `Between...` instead of `Duplicate Values...`
[image]

If you dont have excel installed, you may consider alternative freeware -  [LibreOffice](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.libreoffice.org%2F&ei=RWCNVZzBA6bymQXAoZ2ABQ&usg=AFQjCNGh0I4bkYIBG2243ng8DOCD4k4yfQ&sig2=swtPeubLDe3RjNe551Tiig) or Online application [Google Doc](https://www.google.com.hk/intl/zh-HK/docs/about/)

Comment: Thanks, the issue however is that the numbers are spread throughout a document. for example doing a netstat on 100 machines and wanting all the port values of a certain range highlighted. The time it would take me to copy and paste all the numbers into exceed and remove the other information, I would have been able to do it manually. If I just had a list of numbers then this would be by far the best. I'll edit my question however and upvote for the work around. Thanks!.

Comment: The answer may be "No", using MS Word though and what you stated may be the best possible solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I concur with this solution. Especially if its about a netstat dump, just select all, copy, paste in excel, then use the function "text to columns" to transform the lines into cells and have it possible to highlight cells based on various conditions/search & replace.

Comment: upvote for `text to columns`, which i was planing to explain to him :)  Unless the data is totally random, no delimiter can be use to split the data (e.g. copy and pasting 100 news from SCMP), `text to columns` is usually working

Comment: Great. Sad that Word can't do it, but I really appreciate you giving a good solution! I'll try copying to excel. I feel this will take a 4 hour task and reduce to under 20 minutes. You have both been a big help, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, you could also do a wildcard Find and Replace in Word.

In "Find what", enter: `.2[34][0-9]{2}[!0-9]`

That will find a full stop (a.k.a. period or dot), followed by `2`, which must then be followed by a `3` or `4`, which is then followed by two (2) digits, and is followed by a character that is not another digit.

That limits it to 2300 to 2499 (so omits the 2500 – but you could do a one-off search for that).  By including the not 0-9 at the end, it won't pick up 23000 or 23456, for example.

Ensure you have clicked the "More" button so you can see all the options.
Tick "Use wildcards".

For "Replace with", leave it blank, but on the Format button at bottom left click Highlight (so under your "Replace with" textbox you'll now see the word "Highlight").

(Before you do this, ensure you have highlighted some text with a colour so your highlighter is set to a colour, and not no colour, otherwise your replace won't "highlight").

[image: Replace All]