# Selecting ALL numbers in word to allow to highlight and change to BOLD

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I saw a previous post labeled: “[Find and high light all numbers in a certain range: MS Word 2013](https://superuser.com/q/933096/167207)”

The answer was specific for the asker but doesn’t totally solve my problem.

I am trying to highlight all numbers to allow a global BOLDing of the number as per this block of text:

> • MX-01   prep bench
> •     B & S – YCJSF-**1** – Steamer
> •     Approx **750**mm width x **900**mm depth x **1300**mm height
> •     Jet burners to be **130**Mj
> •     Provide with REMOVABLE stainless steel HEAT DEFLECTOR fitted to rear of upstand at top
> •     Available from B & S Ph +**61** ( **03** ) **9469 4754**   info@bscommercialkitchens.com
> •     Provide flexible gas connection and safety cable to allow max **1200**mm travel
> •     Ensure length of gas line after installation is min **100**mm longer than cable when fully extended to ensure no visible kinking or crushing of the gas line is evident
> Refer Section **6.0** Noodle Cookers in Associated Works Section of specification for general specification details

I would like all numbers to be bold but when I used the previous post after changing a couple of things to `[12345678910][0-9]{2}[!0-9]` I missed some of the bolding especially on the 1 numbers at the front of a number block and also it bolded the first `m` in eg `1200mm`

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

- Find what: `([0-9]{1,})`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Click on Format > Font > Font style, set it to Bold.
- Search options: Use Wildcards

See image below for reference. Click Replace All to change the numbers' font to bold.

[image: IMG:]